# How to determine optimum prepared statement cache size when using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching, size, prepared-statement

AFAIK, Hibernate transforms all sql to prepared statement form before issuing it to the database. When tuning the application, the size of prepared statement cache can be an important factor. How to determine the optimum value when using Hibernate, given that it creates prepared statements “under the hood”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you'd try to obtain such statistics from your database after letting the application run its normal course for a certain period of time.

You can also enable [statistics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics) and [SQL logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) in Hibernate configuration and analyze the data obtained.